# React map list in function return HTML code

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating my application menu and have the following error in my function :

> Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

```
function buildListItemWithNavLink(prop, key, activePro, listItemClasses, whiteFontClasses){
return (
  <div>
    <NavLink
      properties
    >
      <ListItem button className={classes.itemLink + listItemClasses}>
        <ListItemText
            properties
        />
      </ListItem>
    </NavLink>
    {prop.subMenus != null ? (
      prop.subMenus.map((propSubMenu, keySubMenu) => {
        if(propSubMenu.path != undefined)
          return buildListItemWithNavLink(propSubMenu, keySubMenu, activePro, listItemClasses, whiteFontClasses);
        else
          return buildListItemWithoutNavLink(propSubMenu, whiteFontClasses);
      })
    ) : null}
  </div>
);
}
```

My operation is called in a var :

```
var links = (
<List className={classes.list}>
  {routes.map((prop, key) => {
    if (prop.redirect) return null;
    var activePro = " ";
    var listItemClasses;
    listItemClasses = classNames({
      [" " + classes[color]]: activeRoute(prop.path)
    });

    const whiteFontClasses = classNames({
      [" " + classes.whiteFont]: activeRoute(prop.path)
    });

      return buildListItemWithNavLink(prop, key, activePro, listItemClasses, whiteFontClasses);
  })}
</List>
);
```

I don't understand the problem.
My goal is to create a menu with sub-menu

Comment: You need to add key prop to item that is returned from `buildListItemWithNavLink` function. React needs keys when rendering a list of elements inside one parent to handle efficient rendering when an item is added or removed.

Comment: I don't understand your response.

Comment: please try the answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)